# How to make the corners of a domain line in qgis rounded

Tags: python, qgis

I have an array of `QgsPointXY` that makes a line with lots of vertices. The question is, how can I round the corners. Here is what I mean:

[image]

```py
def __round(line: list[QgsPoint], radius: float) -> QgsGeometry:
        rounded_line = QgsGeometry()

        for i in range(len(line) - 2):
            # Get the start and end points of the line segment
            start_point = line[i]
            end_point = line[i + 1]

            # Calculate the midpoint between the start and end points
            mid_point = QgsPoint(
                (start_point.x() + end_point.x()) / 2, (start_point.y() + end_point.y()) / 2)

            # Calculate the direction angle of the line segment
            direction_angle = start_point.azimuth(end_point)

            # Calculate the perpendicular angle to the direction angle
            perpendicular_angle = direction_angle + 90

            # Convert the perpendicular angle to radians
            perpendicular_angle_radians = perpendicular_angle * 3.14159 / 180

            # Calculate the center of the circular arc
            center_point = QgsPoint(mid_point.x() + radius * math.cos(perpendicular_angle_radians),
                                    mid_point.y() + radius * math.sin(perpendicular_angle_radians))

            # Calculate the start and end angles of the circular arc
            start_angle = direction_angle - 90
            end_angle = direction_angle + 90

            # Create the circular arc using QgsCircularString
            circular_string = QgsCircularString.fromTwoPointsAndCenter(
                start_point, center_point, end_point)

            # Add the circular arc to the rounded line
            rounded_line.addPart(circular_string.toPolyline(), False)

        return rounded_line

line = [QgsPointXY(1,1), QgsPointXY(50, 1.2), QgsPointXY(120,2), ...]

rounded_line = __round(line, 2)
```

The question is, how to implement the function `__round`. Now Because of poor docs I cant find anything helpful.

The black line is what I have (array of verticies). I need somehow to round all the corners (red). All corners must have the same radius (float).

I've spent a lot and still can't find the answer. The official docs of Qgis for Python are very poor (Maybe I miss something? If yes, would be very grateful for the link for some normal docs)